# How to use eval() function on string of ints?

Tags: python, string, eval

With a string of ints:

```
myStr = '3848202160702781329 2256714569201620911 1074847147244043342'
```

How could one do an average of the string ints while keeping the string data type ?
Here what I thought in pseudo code:

```
sum = 0
res = eval(myStr[i] + ' + sum') 
avg = res/len(myStr)
```

Comment: You do not have a "string of ints". That doesn't make sense. You have a `str` object. `eval` is for evaluating strings that represent valid Python source code expressions. Your current string does not. What do you mean "while keeping the string data type?" What exactly are you trying to avoid and why?

Comment: If you want the average, why not something like `data = list(map(int, myStr.split()))` then `avg = sum(data) / len(data)`?

Comment: You should _never_ use `eval()`. It is a very unsafe function.

Comment: Somehow, you need to create a valid eval() expression. In this case, you need to add a + between each number you want to add. print(eval(myStr.replace(" ", " + "))) would accomplish this, but then you still need to divide to get your average. Not sure eval() is the best way to accomplish this, but that's a start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If You want to get the average of those integers in that string this is one way:

```py
myStr = '3848202160702781329 2256714569201620911 1074847147244043342'
print(sum(lst := [int(x) for x in myStr.split()]) / len(lst))
```

basically You get the sum of a list of those integers that are in that string and also use that operator (forgot the name) to assign that list to a variable while simultaneously return that value, then just divide the sum by the length of that list

EDIT1, 2, 3: just remembered, it is called `walrus operator`, some info can be found [here (video by Lex Fridman)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN2TTiGpDvM) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-walrus-operator-7971cd339d7d), as well as other places, also it requires Python version of 3.8 or higher

EDITn: the reason behind the use of the walrus operator is that it allowed to not repeat code in this one-liner, otherwise the list comprehension would have been used twice (in `sum` and in `len`) which could affect performance for very large lists (and I wanted it to be a one-liner)

Comment: I still have to get used to the walrus operator and this code seems like a very clever way to use it.

Comment: @Matthias to be fair ... this is my literal first time using it like this (tho I had heard about it (and somewhat knew how it functions), I never really have used it)

Comment: Actually I use very often the walrus operator, but the BDFL of Python didn't like it at all: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN2TTiGpDvM

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO yes, but it is still pretty great (tho I don't use it as much and I can easily see how it can make code less readable pretty quickly), also that is the same video I have linked in my answer

Comment: Sorry ‍♀️I had not noticed it 

Answer (score 3):

You could split the string, and map it to integers then find the sum of the list. Lastly divide the sum by the length of the split list.

```
myStr = '3848202160702781329 2256714569201620911 1074847147244043342'
print(sum(map(int,myStr.split()))/len(myStr.split()))
```

output

```
2.3932546257161487e+18
```

Comment: This has the slight disadvantage that you have to split the string twice.

Comment: yes that is true, but I did not want to copy your method of using walrus operator :). Out of kindness.

Comment: @BuddyBob unexpected (kinda) - but I am the one that used `walrus operator` ... what similar nicknames we got, P.S. I wouldn't mind if You used it

Answer (score 2):

Since (the absolute valid) other answers show one-liner solutions I'd like to show the different steps. This might help to understand what's going on.

```
>>> myStr = '3848202160702781329 2256714569201620911 1074847147244043342'
>>> data = myStr.split()
>>> data
['3848202160702781329', '2256714569201620911', '1074847147244043342']
>>> data = list(map(int, data))
>>> data
[3848202160702781329, 2256714569201620911, 1074847147244043342]
>>> sum(data)
7179763877148445582
>>> sum(data) / len(data)
2.3932546257161487e+18
```

Comment: If you do `sum(data) // len(data)` you will get a long int result that is a max error of 2 in 2^18 - more accurate than double float precision...